# Does local martingale have the same mean value as well?

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

We know that if $\{M_n\}$ is a martingale, we know from definition of martingale that $E(M_n) = M_0$ for all $n \geq 0$. However, if we only know that a sequence of random variables $\{X_n\}$ is a local martingale, do we still have the result that
$$E(X_n) = X_0, \forall n\geq 0?$$

And why?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the first paragraph of [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_martingale), no:

> Every martingale is a local martingale; every bounded local martingale
>   is a martingale; in particular, every local martingale that is bounded
>   from below is a supermartingale, and every local martingale that is
>   bounded from above is a submartingale; however, in general a local
>   martingale is not a martingale, because its expectation can be
>   distorted by large values of small probability. In particular, a
>   driftless diffusion process is a local martingale, but not necessarily
>   a martingale.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But is there any concrete examples showing that local martingales may not preserve the mean value at each time?

Comment: @Sean http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115738/finding-an-example-of-a-discrete-time-strict-local-martingale